# python: split a string based on first occurrence of any nonnumeric character

Tags: python, regex, string

i have strings of the following form:

```
s = '567a45b'
```

the general format being a set of numbers followed by a single letter, and again a set of numbers followed by a single letter. each of the 2 sequences of numbers can be varied in length and the letters can be anything A-Z.

i am looking for a general way to split this up into:

```
['567a','45b']
```

so essentially split up based on where the first non-numeric character is

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
temp = []
result = []
for c in list(s):
    if not c.isnumeric():
        temp.append(c)
        result.append("".join(temp))
        temp = []
    else:
        temp.append(c)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['567a', '45b']
```

Answer (score 2):

This expression also might simply work:

```
import re

print(re.findall(r"(\d+[A-Za-z])", "567a45b567a45b567a45b"))
```

#### Output

```
['567a', '45b', '567a', '45b', '567a', '45b']
```

Comment: But, this doesn't split a string, it matches it in groups of digits and alpha char. It will miss a whole lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression, and split it on your pattern, but match that pattern. Throw away all the empty segments between your splitting pattern.

```py
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re

>>> re.split(r"(\d+\D+)", "567a45b")
['', '567a', '', '45b', '']

>>> re.split(r"(\d+\D+)", "567a45b")[1::2]
['567a', '45b']
```

Those backslash things one or more numbery things followed by one or more nonnumbery things.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

> based on first occurrence of any group of alpha (nonnumeric) characters

Here you go, this will give you a clean `split()`s in the strings middle.
Note that you shouldn't just split on the *first* alpha char since
there could be a series of alpha characters, each of which will be split
into an element.

`(?i)(?<=[a-z])(?![a-z]|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/8BYChO/1

Expanded version

```
 (?i)
 (?<= [a-z] )
 (?! [a-z] | $ )
```

---

Also, an fyi;  you will blow up the split if you rely on digits being present
before the alpha chars.